# VBA AutoFilter and copy visible data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the below macro to open a file, filter column D to "Pps" and copy visible data to destination worksheet, after which i clear the filter (the coding works so far) then filter column D again, to "Pkt". however, the filter result returns empty instead.. Any idea what went wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Generate_cmb_Click()    
Dim SourceSQ01Wb As Workbook, DestWb As Workbook
Dim SourceSQ01Ws As Worksheet, DestPpsWs As Worksheet, DestPktWs As Worksheet
Dim SourceSQ01FilterRng As Range, SourceSQ01CopyRng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set SourceSQ01Wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\\SQ01.xlsx", , True) 'Readonly = True
Set SourceSQ01Ws = SourceSQ01Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
SourceSQ01Ws.Range("A:E,G:G,I:N,P:S,U:X,AD:AE,AH:AI").EntireColumn.Delete
Set SourceSQ01FilterRng = SourceSQ01Ws.Range("A1:K" & LastRow(SourceSQ01Ws))

Set DestWb = ThisWorkbook
Set DestPpsWs = DestWb.Worksheets("Packet Plus")
Set DestPktWs = DestWb.Worksheets("Packet")

'---------------- FOR PPS ----------------


'Filter and set the filter field & criteria
SourceSQ01FilterRng.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=Pps"

With SourceSQ01FilterRng.Parent.AutoFilter.Range
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Set SourceSQ01CopyRng to the visible cells in SourceSQ01FilterRng without the header row
    Set SourceSQ01CopyRng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) _
              .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not SourceSQ01CopyRng Is Nothing Then

        'Copy and paste the cells into DestPpsWs below the existing data
        SourceSQ01CopyRng.Interior.Color = xlNone
        SourceSQ01CopyRng.Copy


            With DestPpsWs.Range("A" & LastRow(DestPpsWs) + 1)
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With
    End If


End With

Application.Goto DestPpsWs.Range("A1")


'---------------- FOR PKT ----------------  

'Clear filer
    SourceSQ01FilterRng.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False



'Filter and set the filter field & criteria
SourceSQ01FilterRng.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=Pkt"

With SourceSQ01FilterRng.Parent.AutoFilter.Range
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Set SourceSQ01CopyRng to the visible cells in SourceSQ01FilterRng without the header row
    Set SourceSQ01CopyRng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) _
              .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not SourceSQ01CopyRng Is Nothing Then

        'Copy and paste the cells into DestPktWs below the existing data
        SourceSQ01CopyRng.Interior.Color = xlNone
        SourceSQ01CopyRng.Copy


            With DestPpsWs.Range("A" & LastRow(DestPktWs) + 1)
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With
    End If


End With

Application.Goto DestPktWs.Range("A1")




'--------------------------------


'Close SourceSQ01Wb without saving changes
'SourceSQ01Wb.Close (False)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0


End Function
```

Comment: did you step through the code, line-by-line, and make sure the previous filter has indeed been removed?

Comment: And is there data with "Pkt"???

Comment: why over complicate with an auto filter which you remove later. I think it'd be easier to iterate through the cells of column D, and when the contents match your criteria, copy that row to the new worksheet? you could even combine the pps and pkt procedure if yo write the procedure as a sub with the criteria as input. `Private Sub CopyData(Criteria as String)`

Answer (score 0):

The second (PKT) paste process is pasting to the **DestPpsWs** worksheet, not the **DestPktWs** worksheet. Your results are ending up on the **DestPpsWs** worksheet at a position determined by the LastRow on the **DestPktWs** worksheet.

Should be:

```
            With DestPktWs.Range("A" & LastRow(DestPktWs) + 1)
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With
```

It was on line 83 in my simulation. Might be slightly different on yours.

To avoid copy & paste mistakes like that, I will loop through an array which holds the individual parameters for repetitious processes. Here is a quick rewrite using a loop.

```
Public Sub Generate_cmb_Click_Loops()
    Dim v As Long, vDestinations() As Variant
    Dim SourceSQ01Wb As Workbook, DestWb As Workbook
    Dim SourceSQ01Ws As Worksheet
    Dim SourceSQ01FilterRng As Range, SourceSQ01CopyRng As Range

    vDestinations = Array("Packet Plus", "Pps", _
                          "Packet", "Pkt")

    'turn back on after debugging
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set SourceSQ01Wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\\SQ01.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    Set SourceSQ01Ws = SourceSQ01Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    SourceSQ01Ws.Range("A:E,G:G,I:N,P:S,U:X,AD:AE,AH:AI").EntireColumn.Delete
    'currentRegion does not depend on visible cells like .Find does
    Set SourceSQ01FilterRng = SourceSQ01Ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Set DestWb = ThisWorkbook

    '---------------- FOR PPS/PKT ----------------
    With SourceSQ01FilterRng
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 11)  '<~~ A:K
            For v = LBound(vDestinations) To UBound(vDestinations) Step 2

                'check for existing AutoFilter; turn off if found
                If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

                'Filter and set the filter field & criteria
                .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=vDestinations(v + 1)

                ' Set SourceSQ01CopyRng to the visible cells in SourceSQ01FilterRng without the header row
                On Error Resume Next
                'note: resize before offset otherwise (very rarely) it can crash
                Set SourceSQ01CopyRng = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0) _
                          .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not SourceSQ01CopyRng Is Nothing Then

                    'Copy and paste the cells into DestPpsWs below the existing data
                    SourceSQ01CopyRng.Interior.Color = xlNone
                    SourceSQ01CopyRng.Copy

                    With Worksheets(vDestinations(v)).Range("A" & _
                      LastRow(Worksheets(vDestinations(v))) + 1)
                        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        Application.Goto .Parent.Range("A1")
                    End With

                End If

            Next v
        End With
        'check for leftover AutoFilter; turn it off
        If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    '--------------------------------

    'Close SourceSQ01Wb without saving changes
    'SourceSQ01Wb.Close (False)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I removed some redundant code and used the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) to set the filter range. .CurrentRegion does not depend upon visible rows like a [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) so it doesn't matter if the procedure was started with a filter in place on the source worksheet.